# micro blown up with 3V?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, 12v, 5v

I'm attempting to make a 12v blinking light that turns off with a high signal and since I've got some 5v arduino pro minis I though I might do it with them. So I put together a program and a plan

[image]

My idea was, that when the switch is closed, 3-4.6v is applied to pin 3 (logic level high) and my program stops the blinking. 
Testing this with 5v without a voltage divider just pulling pin 3 high or low seemed to work. So I hooked up the voltage divider and tested it with a 12V-14V source. All seemed well until I connected the voltage divider (R1) to 12V (while monitoring the voltage it was outputting) even though I saw only 3V on pin 3 the micro-controller went pop. 
I'm not really sure why it popped, sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm not the best at this stuff. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**Edit:** Genuine question, why do some of my questions get voted down? 
Am I using this site wrong or formatting my questions wrong? I've been trying to learn electronics, but so far this site hasn't been of much help. 
I don't really understand why some people vote down questions without telling the asker what they are doing wrong. If you could explain what they're doing wrong it can help them to not make the same mistake in the future (E.g. formatting wrong, not site applicable etc).

Comment: Is this a 3.3V pro mini? Or a 5V pro mini? (Google tells me there are two kinds.) It's not clear from your writing. Also, are you hooking up 12V directly to pin 24 in the drawing there?

Comment: 5v, I'll add the info

Comment: So may I gather that supplying 12V to "RAW" is okay for your pro mini? (It sounds like a regulator input pin, so the answer might be yes.)

Comment: Yep, what's the voltage regulator input. I believe the ones they use on the pro minis can take a maximum of 16v.

Comment: Stream of logic: 12V is fine on RAW. Internal regulator produces 5V as Vcc. All I/O pins should be capable of accepting input voltages from 0V to 5V without involving the protection diodes. You have a divider that divides 12V by 3 to get 4V out, with a series resistance of about 67k. On paper, there is no possibility that 4V with a series Thevenin resistance of 67k should cause any harm. Therefore, something else is the problem. (Such as directly connecting 12V to an I/O pin.)

Comment: `all seemed well until I connected the voltage divider` .... this statement makes me wonder what you actually did ..... you show a push button switch .... why did you not say `all seemed well until I pressed the button`?

Comment: My intention was to hook it up to a key switch , for testing I simply touched the loose wire to the 12 volt source. I also probed pin three of the microcontroller which showed 3 volts on the pin with the divider hooked up.

Comment: did you measure +3V or -3V ?

Comment: +3v, not really sure how I could end up measuring or even producing negative voltage in this situation

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'pop'.

Comment: Pop noise and Magic Smoke came out, in other words the micro controller was fried

Comment: Your schematic doesn't appear to have Vcc connected nor does it show any supply voltage decoupling. There is also a GND connecttion missing. Please show precisely your full circuit and describe in more detail how you made Vcc.

Comment: I'm legitimately not sure what you mean, everything that needs to be connected to ground is connected to ground. I put PCC there simply to indicate +12 volts Edit: and voltage decoupling? What would I need that for, I may not have mentioned it but I'm getting 12 volts straight from a battery.

Comment: Just a guess - was power already connected to Arduino when you connected resistor divider to source?

Comment: Yes, the Arduino was powered and operational

Comment: Well, then I am out of the ideas. **If** everything was connected as on your schematics it should not have blown.

Comment: I guess I better go make sure I wired everything up correctly

Comment: Nope just checked it's wired up as per the wiring diagram, even cranking the voltage up to 14 volts I only get 4.66v on pin 3. I'm really not sure what's going on here but the microcontroller is definitely fried, it gets noticeably hot to the touch and doesn't respond to any programming commands.

Comment: Just checed the VCC pin on the Arduino and it appears the voltage regulator failed short-circuit and put 12v out frying the microcontroller, the question is why?? I thought the voltage Regulators on these boards can go up to 16 volts absolute Max. I was only feeding 12 volts in, strange. Perhaps I should stick a cheap Buck converter in between?

Comment: @DavidScheiber It's possible that a static discharge damaged something inside the Arduino Pro Mini.

Comment: @Andyaka the block in the schematic is a board (identified as an "Arduino pro mini") hosting an ATmega, not a raw IC.  Hence the various power and ground pins having the same name are tied together internally and they do not all need to be connected the way they would with a bare chip.  Also the supply bypassing, and even regulator, are on board.

Answer (score 1):

Per OP's comment, the voltage regulator had failed and was passing all 12 volts on to the microcontroller.

Comment: "tested it with a 12V-14V source" sounds like it could be automotive, and automotive power busses are notoriously nasty.  Or perhaps the source is an unregulated wall wart.  At any rate, until identified it should be considered an area of suspicion.  Also even a clean 12v source puts a fair thermal load on a linear regulator.